# Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: null

Tags: r, machine-learning, deep-learning, nvidia, h2o

So,

I already installed Nvidia drivers on my ubuntu 16.4 and CUDA and CUDNN. I fixed all problems on this, now it's fine.

It's already setup up and the installation went well.

I want to use h2o.deepwater in R. My code:

```
dlmodel <-  h2o.deepwater(x=predictors, y=response,
                         training_frame=train, 
                         validation_frame=valid, 

                         hidden=c(120,80), epochs=200, 
                         activation="Tanh",

                         seed=1234567,
                         stopping_metric='MSE',
                         classification_stop=0.001,
                         stopping_rounds = 5,
                         backend="tensorflow")
```

But I am getting this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize the native Deep Learning backend: null`

Can anyone help me fix this? I already re-installed R h2o and my gpu drivers.

Comment: install 64bit java manually? https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win8_faq.xml

Answer (score 2):

A common cause for this is that you haven't yet set the environment variables. Please check your installation.

`export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_PATH/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

This is described further here: https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-downloads

Comment: Is there a Windows solution for this?

Comment: We have only built Deep Water for Ubuntu Linux. We do provide Docker images that run in Windows. That would be the easy solution unless you want to built it yourself for Windows. See here: https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-docker-image

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you correctly setup the environment variables - but be aware: the snippets in answer 1 and from the deep water page (https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-downloads) contain a spelling error in the second line. Correctly it should read as:

```
export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_PATH/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```